# Calculation of the daily average

Tags: python, pandas

How to transform this data so that the pm 2.5 pm 10 columns are the average of the whole day. The data I collected (example here below) collects data every 15 minutes.

```
    Pm 2.5  Pm 10   Created At
0   6.00    19.20   2021-06-21 19:00
1   4.70    17.00   2021-06-21 19:15
2   4.80    16.70   2021-06-21 19:30
3   5.10    12.10   2021-06-21 19:45
4   7.90    19.10   2021-06-21 20:00
```

Comment: In the future please add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this will greatly help getting answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's `resample` the dataframe:

```
df['Created At'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created At'])
df.resample('D', on='Created At').mean()
```

---

```
            Pm 2.5  Pm 10
Created At               
2021-06-21     5.7  16.82
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way do it

```
convert the date using to_datetime, grab the date and carry out the mean

df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Created At']).dt.date).mean()
```

```
    Created At  Pm 2.5  Pm 10
0   2021-06-21  5.7     16.82
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Grouper` and then `transform` if you want to preserve the dataframe shape:

```
df['Created At'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created At'])
df[['Pm 2.5', 'Pm 10']] =  df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Created At', freq='D'))\
                          [['Pm 2.5', 'Pm 10']].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
 Pm 2.5 Pm 10   Created At
0   5.7 16.82   2021-06-21 19:00:00
1   5.7 16.82   2021-06-21 19:15:00
2   5.7 16.82   2021-06-21 19:30:00
3   5.7 16.82   2021-06-21 19:45:00
4   5.7 16.82   2021-06-21 20:00:00
```

Comment: When I run your solution i get `Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: That's interesting. Are you sure that you use the columns `[['Pm 2.5', 'Pm 10']]` on the both sides of the last line?